# Blazor Hybrid - How can I achieve saving the captured Photo to android local storage

Tags: blazor, blazor-hybrid

I am using this code as my reference but I couldnt achieve saving it to local storage from android

```
public async void TakePhoto()
{
    if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
    {
        FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();

        if (photo != null)
        {
            // save the file into local storage
            string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);

            using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
            using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

I need the captured photo to be saved in local storage in the android